# Could someone explain this weird looking code, used to setup timers?

Tags: timers, programming

While looking at sketches other people have written, I occasionally come across code that looks somewhat like this:

```
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0;

TCNT1 = 34286;
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);
```

All I know is that is has something to with timing/timers (I think). How can I decipher—and create—code like this? What are `TCCR1A`, `TCCR1B`, `TCNT1`, `CS12`, `TIMSK1`, and `TOIE1`?

Comment: Don't know enough to answer but: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92350/what-is-the-difference-between-tccr1a-and-tccr1b, http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=134602.0, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475482/pulse-width-modulation-pwm-on-avr-studio. Don't know if you've seen these already.

Comment: Download the "Complete" datasheet for your device from the [Atmel website](http://atmel.com/) and read the chapters about timers. The datasheet is surprisingly good to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't weird looking. It's what normal MCU code actually looks like.

What you have here is an example of the concept of *memory-mapped peripherals*. Basically, the MCU hardware has special locations in the SRAM address space of the MCU assigned to it. If you write to these addresses, the bits of the byte written to address *n* control the behaviour of peripheral *m*.

Basically, certain banks of memory literally have little wires running from the SRAM cell to the hardware. If you write a "1" to this bit in that byte, it sets this SRAM cell to a logical high, which then turns on some portion of the hardware.

If you look into the headers for the MCU, there are great big tables of keyword<->address mappings. This is how things like `TCCR1B` etc... are resolved at compile time.

This memory-mapping mechanism is extremely broadly used in MCUs. The ATmega MCU in the arduino use it, as do PIC, ARM, MSP430, STM32 and STM8 MCU series, as well as lots of MCUs I'm not immediately familiar with.

---

*Arduino* code is the weird stuff, with functions that access the MCU control registers indirectly. While this is somewhat "nicer" looking, it's also much slower, and uses a lot more program space.

The mysterious constants are all described in great detail in the [ATmega328P datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet.pdf), which you really should read if you're interested in doing anything more then occationally toggling pins on an arduino.

Select excerpts from the datasheet linked above:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, for example, `TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);` sets the bit `TOIE1` in `TIMSK1`. This is achieved by shifting binary 1 (`0b00000001`) to the left by `TOIE1` bits, with `TOIE1` being defined in a header file as 0. This is then bitwise ORed into the current value of `TIMSK1`, which effectively set this one bit high.

Looking at the documentation for bit 0 of `TIMSK1`, we can see it is described as

> When this bit is written to one, and the I-flag in the Status Register
>   is set (interrupts globally enabled), the Timer/Counter1 Overflow
>   interrupt is enabled. The corresponding Interrupt Vector (See
>   ”Interrupts” on page 57) is executed when the TOV1 Flag, located in
>   TIFR1, is set.

All the other lines should be interpreted in the same manner.

---

Some notes:

You may also see things like `TIMSK1 |= _BV(TOIE1);`. `_BV()` is a [commonly used macro](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_use_bv) originally from the [AVR libc implementation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html). `_BV(TOIE1)` is functionally identical to `(1 << TOIE1)`, with the benefit of better readability.

Also, you may also see lines such as: `TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << TOIE1);` or `TIMSK1 &= ~_BV(TOIE1);`. This has the opposite function of `TIMSK1 |= _BV(TOIE1);`, in that it *unsets* the bit `TOIE1` in `TIMSK1`. This is achieved by taking the bit-mask produced by `_BV(TOIE1)`, performing a bitwise NOT operation on it (`~`), and then ANDing `TIMSK1` by this NOTed value (which is 0b11111110).

Note that in all these cases, the value of things like `(1 << TOIE1)` or `_BV(TOIE1)` are fully resolved at *compile time*, so they functionally reduce to a simple constant, and therefore take no execution time to compute at runtime.

---

Properly written code will *generally* have comments inline with the code that detail what the registers being assigned to do. Here is a fairly simple soft-SPI routine I wrote recently:

```
uint8_t transactByteADC(uint8_t outByte)
{
    // Transfers one byte to the ADC, and receives one byte at the same time
    // does nothing with the chip-select
    // MSB first, data clocked on the rising edge

    uint8_t loopCnt;
    uint8_t retDat = 0;

    for (loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < 8; loopCnt++)
    {
        if (outByte & 0x80)         // if current bit is high
            PORTC |= _BV(ADC_MOSI);     // set data line
        else
            PORTC &= ~(_BV(ADC_MOSI));  // else unset it

        outByte <<= 1;              // and shift the output data over for the next iteration
        retDat <<= 1;               // shift over the data read back

        PORTC |= _BV(ADC_SCK);          // Set the clock high

        if (PINC & _BV(ADC_MISO))       // sample the input line
            retDat |= 0x01;         // and set the bit in the retval if the input is high

        PORTC &= ~(_BV(ADC_SCK));       // set clock low
    }
    return retDat;
}
```

`PORTC` is the register that controls the value of output pins within `PORTC` of the ATmega328P. `PINC` is the register where the *input* values of `PORTC` are available. Fundamentally, things like this are what happen internally when you use the `digitalWrite` or `digitalRead` functions. However, there is a look-up operation that converts the arduino "pin numbers" into actual hardware pin numbers, which takes somewhere in the realm of 50 clock cycles. As you can probably guess, if you're trying to go fast, wasting 50 clock cycles on an operation that should only require 1 is a bit ridiculous.

The above function probably takes somewhere in the realm of 100-200 clock cycles to transfer 8 bits. This entails 24 pin-writes, and 8 reads. This is many, many times faster then using the `digital{stuff}` functions.

Comment: Note that this code should also work with Atmega32u4 (used in Leonardo) as it contains more timers than ATmega328P.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer!! Could you please ellaborate a bit on what you mean by `Arduino code is the weird stuff`? What exactly is unique to Arduino code, that's not usually found in other platforms?

Comment: @Ricardo - Probably 90%+ of small-MCU embedded code uses direct register manipulation. Doing things with indirect utility functions is very much not the common mode of manipulating IO/peripherals. There are some toolkits for abstracting away hardware control (The Atmel ASF, for example), but that's generally written to compile away as much as possible to reduce runtime overhead, and almost invariably requires actually understanding the peripherals by reading the datasheets.

Comment: Basically, arduino stuff, by saying "here are functions that do X", without really bothering to reference the actual documentation or how the hardware is *doing* the things it does, is very much not normal. I understand it's value as a introductory tool, but except for quick prototyping, it's not really ever done in actual professional environments.

Comment: To be clear, the thing that makes arduino code unusual for embedded MCU firmware is not *unique* to arduino code, it's a function of the overall approach. Basically, once you have a decent understanding of the *actual* MCU, doing things properly (e.g. using hardware registers directly) takes little to no additional time. As such, if you want to learn real MCU dev, it's much better to just sit down and understand what your MCU is *actually* doing, rather then relying on someone *else's* abstraction, which tends to be leaky.

Comment: Basically, the whole arduino system is more or less designed to allow low-barrier-of-entry to *non*-programmers. It does this well, but at the same time it doesn't do a good job of forcing end-users to actually *understand* the hardware, simply because that is antithetical to low-barrier-of-entry. I recognize that this can (and is) a valuable stepping-stone for people on the road to learning software/MCU dev, but anyone using it should not be under any illusions that the arduino way is necessarily the best, or even sometimes a good way of doing what it does.

Comment: Note that I may be a bit cynical here, but a lot the behaviours I see in the arduino community are programming anti-patterns. I see a lot of "copy-paste" programming, the treating of libraries as black-boxes, and just general poor design practices in the community at large. Of course, I'm fairly active on EE.stackexchange, so I may have a somewhat slanted view, since I have some moderator tools, and as such see a lot of the closed questions. There is definitely a bias in the arduino questions I've seen there towards "tell me what to C&P to fix", rather then "why is this not working".

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that the very use of C++ is *somewhat* unusual. Most small MCU work is done in pure-C only.

Comment: Got it! It wasn't clear to me what you called indirect access to registers in Arduino, but now I know its the `digitalWrite()` kind of abstractions. It does reduce the barrier for entry, but later becomes a barrier for going forward. But your answer is a great step torwards removing that obstacle. At least for me.

Comment: @Ricardo - Yep. One of the things I really *do* like about arduino as a teaching tool is that it gives you a working environment for playing with the hardware directly, without having to deal with the often most irritating part: the initial bring-up. I've worked on platforms where all I had was a ISP and no working examples. Having to try to troubleshoot why the serial debug interface I was trying to get working without any real debugging interface is.... involved. Having a platform with easy-to-use serial libs is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

`TCCR1A` is timer/counter 1 control register A

`TCCR1B` is timer/counter 1 control register B

`TCNT1` is timer/counter 1's counter value

`CS12` is the 3rd clock select bit for timer/counter 1

`TIMSK1` is timer/counter 1's interrupt mask register

`TOIE1` is the timer/counter 1 overflow interrupt enable

So, the code enables timer/counter 1 at 62.5 kHz and sets the value to 34286. Then it enable the overflow interrupt so when it reaches 65535, it will trigger the interrupt function, most likely labelled as `ISR(timer0_overflow_vect)`

Answer (score 1):

CS12 has a value of 2 since it represents bit 2 of the TCCR1B register.

(1 << CS12) takes the value 1 (0b00000001) and shifts it left 2 times to get (0b00000100).
The order of operations dictates that things in () happen first, so this is done before the "|=" is evaluated.

(1 << CS10) takes the value 1 (0b00000001) and shifts it left 0 times to get (0b00000001).
The order of operations dictates that things in () happen first, so this is done before the "|=" is evaluated.

So now we get TCCR1B |= 0b00000101, which is the same as TCCR1B = TCCR1B | 0b00000101.

Since "|" is "OR", all the bits other than CS12 in TCCR1B are unaffected.